# Android Java Buttons coordinates

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, button

I want to resize buttons if the screen is big . So I have done it using this method . I got screen size and put button width screenWidth/4 . But now I can't put buttons position . I used relative layout and I put their position from xml but when I change their sizes the are lying each on other at 0,0 position.
[image: tihs is on nexus S]
[image: this is on nexus 10]

Here is XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vahe_muradyan.yourquote.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openCamera"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:text="@string/camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openGallery"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_below="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:text="@string/gallery" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/openCamera"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:text="@string/defaults" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have upploaded images on Nexus S and nexus 10 .

Comment: make your buttons match parent, why do you need to resize them? this is not iphone - android has very good resizing techniques, with both relative and linear layout. Can you post the xml of your buttons?

Comment: If I give them match parent they would be big

Comment: How are you setting their positions? and what do you want the layout to look like?

Comment: what about wrap content?

Comment: wrap content would be small on 10 inch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dimensions per screen size

you need to create in your res folder new folders named

values-sw600dp

and in the normal values folder create an xml file called

dimens.xml

in that file write

```
<dimen name="button_width">70dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height>70dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_text_size">14sp</dimen>
```

in your values-sw600dp create another dimens.xml file

in it write

```
<dimen name="button_width">140dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height>140dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_text_size">20sp</dimen>
```

**//play with the sizes to find the good fit**

in your xml file write this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.vahe_muradyan.yourquote.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openCamera"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:text="@string/camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openGallery"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_below="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:text="@string/gallery" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openDefaults"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/openCamera"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttom"
        android:text="@string/defaults" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The system will choose the correct values based on the device you run the app on.

The buttons will be big enough (providing you give good values in values-sw600dp/dimens.xml file)

This is the folder tree:
[image]

have fun!

Comment: I will try it but why the folder name is sw600dp?

Comment: 7 inch tablets 10 inch tablets, devices that were made in mid 2013 and devices that were made in 2014. (2014 devices are mostly xhdpi and xxhdpi even though they are phone sized) however, if you don't create a sw720dp folder, your sw600dp will be used . the term sw600dp means screen width **at least ** 600dp

Comment: so sw720dp would mean "at least 720dp screen width"